# no Errors but no Result

Tags: ruby, regex, counter

I need to find each occurrence of "$" and change it to a number using a count. eg `str = "foo $ bar $ foo $ bar $ * run code here * => "foo 1 bar 2 foo 3 bar 4`

It feels like this should be a lot easier than i'm making it out to be. Here's my code:

```
def counter(file)
  f = File.open(file, "r+")
  count = 0
  contents = f.readlines do |s|

    if s.scan =~ /\$/
      count += 1
      f.seek(1)
      s.sub(/\$/, count.to_s)
    else
      puts "Total changes: #{count}"
    end
  end
end
```

However I'm not sure if I'm meant to be using `.match`, `.scan`, `.find` or whatever else.

When i run this it doesn't come up with any errors but it doesn't change anything either.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a loop.

Comment: Where are you sending the output? In addition to missing a loop, you don't seem to output the results of substitution anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for [scan](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is incorrect and it should throw error.

You can try something along this line:

```
count = 0
str = "foo $ bar $ foo $ bar $ "
occurences = str.scan('$')
# => ["$", "$", "$", "$"]
occurences.size.times do str.sub!('$', (count+=1).to_s) end
str
# => "foo 1 bar 2 foo 3 bar 4 "
```

**Explanation:**
I am finding all occurences of `$` in the string, then I am using [sub!](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21) in iteration as it replaces only the first occurrence at a time.

**Note:** You may want to improve `scan` line by using regex with boundary match instead of plain `"$"` as it will replace `$` even from within words. Eg: `exa$mple` will also get replace to something like: `exa1mple`

**Why your code is not throwing error?**

If you read the description about [readlines](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines), you will find:

> Reads the entire file specified by name as individual lines, and
>   returns those lines in an array.

As it reads the entire file at once there is no value passing block along this method. Following example will make it more clear:

```
 contents = f.readlines do |s|
     puts "HELLO"
 end
 # => ["a\n", "b\n", "c\n", "d\n", "asdasd\n", "\n"] #lines of file f
```

As you can see "HELLO" never gets printed, showing the block code is never executed.